# `AXFocusedUIElement` <- does not get focused element (folder, file), it points to `Finder` menu

Tags: macos

trying to reproduce right-click context menu on my Mac.
I found such an article:

https://beebom.com/how-right-click-using-keyboard-mac/

I did accordingly but when I click my keyboard shortcut I get `Finder` menu not a currently selected file/folder menu.

This is an `apple script` used,

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "System Events" to set frontApp to name of first process whose frontmost is true
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process frontApp
        set _selection to value of attribute "AXFocusedUIElement"
        tell _selection to perform action "AXShowMenu"
    end tell
end tell
return input
end run
```

Spent hours trying to get this basic and obvious to every `Windows` user functionality to work, lost of time and very frustrating!

I think code is correct, maybe there is something specific on my computer that stops it from working as expected?

Please help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood what is actually not working for you, but i had problem to reproduce the same script, once i wrote it in Automator.app i tried to press "play" button to see if the script was working and it was telling me something like  "syntax error, can't get attribute AXFocusedUIElement of application process Automator" (from memory, not sure it's exactly what was written)

and struggled for a while as well untill i realised there was a pop window that i didn't see, saying me that "automator wants permission to control this computer using accessibility features (this thing in the system preference, security and privacy, privacy, accessibility), so i opened, there was a list of apps allowed to control my computer, i ticked Automator.app and after that it worked
Then every app that i was trying to do a right click was showing me the same pop up and i had to do the same for each one (safari, finder etc...)
And then it worked

Hope might help you!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue.

Allow 'Finder' to control computer at System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Privacy>Accessibility.

Worked for me