# `AXFocusedUIElement` does not seem to exist

Tags: attributes, applescript

I have a problem getting the same right-click Mac script to work as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204783/axfocuseduielement-does-not-get-focused-element-folder-file-it-points-t).  Same steps, trying to run the same AppleScript-- namely,

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "System Events" to set frontApp to name of first process whose frontmost is true
tell application "System Events"
  tell application process frontApp
    set _selection to value of attribute "AXFocusedUIElement"
    tell _selection to perform action "AXShowMenu"
  end tell
end tell
return input
end run
```

In my case, when I get to the second double-indented line, I get the following error:

```
Can’t get action "AXShowMenu" of missing value.
```

Just to see what's happening, I added a line `display dialog _selection`.  The value that comes back is: `msng`.

In other words, it seems that when I ask to `tell _selection to perform action "AXShowMenu"`, the _selection seems to indicate a missing value.

p.s., I already did the solution named in the above-mentioned answer.

Is there another name I should use to get the AXFocusedUIElement?

Comment: Not every app or window (etc…) possesses every accessibility feature. Before you try to get a value can you confirm that they actually exist in your app?

Comment: The same thing happens in every app.  Is there a way to see which attributes are available to choose from?

Comment: First, `activate` the app in question. There are a couple of approaches to try. If you use the 'Accessibility Inspector' (its own app but also accessible via xcode), then you can click on ui controls and get convoluted information about whatever you click on.

Comment: Your specific error is arising due to you not fully specifying the element. You have to build the entire path, e.g. for a safari rendition of apple's home page: `tell static text 1 of group 2 of group 2 of group 2 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 to perform action "AXShowMenu"`. Offhand, I suspect that the preceding line isn't actually doing anything (except setting a variable to nothing).